# Sqlbulkcopy Excessive Memory Consumtion even with EnableStreaming and low BatchSize

Tags: sql-server, oracle, powershell

I try to bulk load data from Oracle to SqlServer through Powershell Sqlserver Module Sqlbulkcopy

On small Data, everything works fine, but on big Datasets, even if bachsize and streaming are set, sqlbulkcopy is taking all the memory available... until an out of memory

Also the notify function seems to give no answer, so I guess even with streaming=True, the process first load everything to memory...
What did I missed ?

```
$current = Get-Date

#copy table from Oracle table to SQL Server table
add-type -path "D:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll";
#define oracle connectin string
$conn_str = "cstr"

# query for oracle table
$qry = "

SELECT
             ID,CREATEDT,MODIFIEDDT
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE  source.ISSYNTHETIC=0 AND source.VALIDFROM >= TO_Date('2019-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') 
";
# key (on the left side) is the source column while value (on the right side) is the target column
[hashtable] $mapping = @{'ID'='ID';'CREATEDT'='CREATEDT';'MODIFIEDDT'};
 
$adapter = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($qry, $conn_str);
#$info = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
#Write-Host ( $info | Format-Table | Out-String)
$dtbl = new-object System.Data.DataTable('MYTABLE');
#this Fill method will populate the $dtbl with the query $qry result
$adapter.Fill($dtbl);
#define sql server target instance
$sqlconn = "cstr";

$sqlbc = new-object system.data.sqlclient.Sqlbulkcopy($sqlconn)

$sqlbc.BatchSize = 1000;
$sqlbc.EnableStreaming = $true;
$sqlbc.NotifyAfter = 1000;
$sqlbc.DestinationTableName="DWHODS.MYTABLE";


#need to tell $sqlbc the column mapping info
foreach ($k in $mapping.keys)
{
    $colMapping = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping($k, $mapping[$k]);
    $sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add($colMapping) | out-null
}

$sqlbc.WriteToServer($dtbl);
$sqlbc.close;

$end= Get-Date
$diff= New-TimeSpan -Start $current -End $end

Write-Output "import needed : $diff"
```

Comment: Well the problem would be `$adapter.Fill`; you request an in-memory copy of all the data before actually bulk copying it. That's extremely inefficient (especially since `DataTable` is very un-economical with memory).  Use the overload of `WriteToServer` that accepts a `DbDataReader` directly, and `OracleCommand.ExecuteReader`. (The `EnableStreaming` is not necessary and does not do what you think it does.)

Comment: Many thanks for your input, that was the problem indeed, I was able to rewrite it to use the reader directly, and now it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jeroen, I changed the code like this, now its no more consuming memory :

```
$oraConn =  New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($conn_str);
$oraConn.Open();
$command = $oraConn.CreateCommand();
$command.CommandText=$qry;
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

...

$sqlbc.WriteToServer($reader);
```